# Are the different uses of "Master" in relation to Jedi ever discussed

Tags: star-wars, jedi

As far as I can tell the word Master is used in 3 contexts, in regards to Jedi.

1. Jedi Master was a rank in the Jedi Order given to powerful Jedi, many of whom were leaders within the
   Order.
2. A Padawan learner would be assigned to a Master who could be a Jedi of any rank(Knight or Master). In
   this case master is synonymous with teacher.
3. Many non-Jedi would use the term "Master Jedi" when talking to any Jedi regardless of rank. In this
   case master is used as an honorific.

Are there any cases in universe, canon or legends, where this is discussed or where it leads to confusion?

Comment: You might want to mention that calling someone a “master” is like a student calling a lecturer “professor” or a head of state “Mr President”, it’s a sign of respect

Comment: Further to @Boolean's point, we also have "Sir" which carries different meanings in different contexts; as a formal title for a knight, the correct way to address senior officers in a military context, and as respectful way of addressing any man you don't know well enough to use their first name.

Comment: Also, for those outside the order it may simply be a matter of ignorance as to whether a Jedi is a padawan, a knight, or a master - after all, Anakin was addressed as "Master Jedi" on Naboo while he was still a padawan (and was mightily peeved when Padme corrected this).

Answer (score 2):

I cannot give an in-universe answer, but I can draw a comparison to real-world examples, with an explanation.

### It's a way to address someone in their position

Let's take the President of the United States as an example. The president is addresses as "Mr.President" or "Madame President" as it is a sign of respect according to their job. In a similar fashion, you would also address a medical professional as "nurse" or "doctor", regardless of their actual job title.

### It's a sign of respect

If I draw a comparison to biblical times (pre-50AD), prophets and teachers of the law were addressed as *Master* or *Teacher* as they were seen as being more knowledgable and to have a better understanding than their students and followers.